# A function in usual topology

Tags: general-topology

How can the function in usual topology $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ be neither open nor closed. I found that the interval (0,1) is mapped to [1/2,1] therefore it is not open. But I could not think of an example for the closed part. Can somebody help me

Comment: Hint: the whole real line is closed, what is it mapped to?

Comment: Generally speaking, the image of a compact set under a continuous real function is always compact, and hence closed. So, if you're looking for proof that a real function is not a closed map, you'll have to look at closed *unbounded* sets.

Answer (score 0):

$f[\Bbb Z] = \{\frac{1}{n^2+1}\mid n=0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ which is not closed as it does not contain $0$, which *is* a limit point of the set.